# Where Can I find the Developers Survey Dataset?

Tags: data-request, survey

Where can I find the yearly Survey dataset of Developers(developer experience from career satisfaction and job search to education and opinions on open-source software)?

Comment: can you provide more information about this? what yearly survey? who publishes it? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently here

### [Stack Overflow Annual Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey)

**2020**

Nearly 65,000 responses fielded from over 180 countries and dependent territories, the 2020 Annual Developer Survey examines all aspects of the developer experience from career satisfaction and job search to education and opinions on open-source software.

[View Survey Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfGerWeWkcyQ9GX9x20rdSGj7WtEpzBB/view?usp=sharing)

**2019**

Nearly 90,000 developers took the 20-minute survey.

[View Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QOmVDpd8hcVYqqUXDXf68UMDWQZP0wQV)

**2018**

Nearly 100,000 developers took the 30-minute survey

[View Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1_9On2-nsBQIw3JiY43sWbrF8EjrqrR4U)

**2017**

Nearly 64,000 developers took the survey

[View Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6ZlG_Eygdj-c1kzcmUxN05VUXM)

**2016**

Nearly 56,033 coders in 173 countries took the survey

[View Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2016) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0DL28AqnGsrV0VldnVIT1hyb0E)

**2015**

26,086 people from 157 countries participated in a 45-question survey. 6,800 identified as full-stack developers, 1,900 as mobile developers, 1,200 as front-end developers, 2 as farmers, and 12,000 as something else.

[View Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2015) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0DL28AqnGsra1psanV1MEdxZk0)

**2014**

The survey sample of 7,500 responses from 96 countries.

[View Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/?_ga=2.174702625.2065321923.1595169812-403292418.1587981474) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0DL28AqnGsrempjMktvWFNaQzA)

**2013**

Nearly 10,000 responses

[View Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/?_ga=2.136997939.2065321923.1595169812-403292418.1587981474) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0DL28AqnGsrenpPNTc5UE1PYW8)

**2012**

[View Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/survey-results/?_ga=2.106193920.2065321923.1595169812-403292418.1587981474) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0DL28AqnGsrX3JaZWVwWEpHNWM)

**2011**

Morethan 2500 responses

[View Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/11/survey-says/?_ga=2.237751939.2065321923.1595169812-403292418.1587981474) • [Download Full Data Set (CSV)](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bx0LyhBTBZQgUGVYaGx3SzdUQ1U)